# Passing dynamic methods to custom directive in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am creating custom directive where I need to assign function inside object which will be used while passing to my directive. However if I pass method by writing directly name of the function inside template, its working fine. But If I assign that method reference to one of my object properties and then I am using that in my template to passing it to directive but that is not working.

You can see here - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y85Ft/362/)

You can see in console. Click on Save button, it will call save function inside directive but from there I am calling controller method which is not working. But if you write function name `blabla` instead `dynamicMethods.myMethod` then it will call but in that I got undefined inside alert.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, paste the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it almost right.

First mistake was when you defined `dynamicMethods` object you're referencing `$scope.blabla` which didn't yet exist.

Second mistake was when you're passing values to the `accept` function call which you've bound to parent scope, you need to pass it as:

```
$scope.accept({msg: "from dir"})
```

where `msg` is a local variable named that can be used in the expression value of `accept` attribute on your custom directive call `<editkeyvalue accept="dynamicMethods.myMethod(msg)" ...`

I've updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y85Ft/363/) accordingly.

When you write `accept: "&"` you're telling angular to

1. use [`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service to parse expression (`dynamicMethods.myMethod(msg)`)
2. "bind" (through [javascript closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)) `$scope` of the function returned from step 1 to the original scope (controller's scope in your case)
3. store the function inside `accept` property of your directive local scope.

Now if you inspect content's of `$scope.accept` just before you call it in directive you'll something similar to:

```
function (locals) {
  return parentGet(parentScope, locals);
}
```

where `locals` is an object with local variables used when the we reach evaluation of function returned from `$parse`. Since there are no named parameters in javascript and we wan't to somehow point that the value local variable `msg` is "from dir" we're passing it as a simple object where key indicates variable name `{msg: "from dir"}`.

Angular will look at the expression (a string) to evaluate and find that `msg` is inside brackets thus it looks like a parameter, which value can be find in `locals` object.

When the time comes to call the actual function angular will convert `locals` object to regular array - preserving order of parameters it read from the expression and call the function in a way similar to:

```
var locals = {msg: "from dir"};
var targetFn = dynamicMethods.myMethod;
var context = dynamicMethods;
targetFn.apply(context, ["from dir"]);
```

Hope that helps a bit in understanding what is going on.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain me about parent and child scope respective to custom directive. As in directive I already created isolated scope which is I think separate from scope then why we need to pass msg inside object. Its working but I don't understand what's happening behind this.